# Xcode WebView part of a page

Tags: ios, webview

I'm working on an iOS app and need to place a web view on a view controller...but I only need a certain portion of it to be shown (the title). Does anyone know how to do this? I would REALLY appreciate any help!

Comment: Why do you want to use a webview if all you want to display is a title ? You can get the title and display it using a simple control rather than webview. Give some more info on your question.

Comment: Can you please attach screen shot..?

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly, well basically I need to show a PREVIEW of a particular web page on the home page view controller of my app, with the main body of the page presented in a webview on the next view controller. Essentially, this page to be displayed (and hence the preview on the home view controller) needs to be updated every day, which is why I started using a webview in the first place. If using a web view is not the easiest way of doing this, I would be more than open to anything else! :)

Comment: @user3903928 , if u need only text you can parse the html and get the strings & use label to display the title .

Comment: I only just started on this website, apparently it's not letting me put images up :/

Comment: @user3903928, if you know the content (like title ,desc , image) in advance that you are going to put in webview, you can parse the html and construct a required html to display .

Answer (score 0):

Just set the frame `size` (size where you want to display the title)required for the `UIWebView`.

Also you definitely can set the `UIWebview` to whatever size you wish to.

Comment: Thanks man, I did that but problem is that it only displays the top left-hand corner of my page, not the title I need, even when I use the scale pages to fit option

Comment: That's obvious. You will have to adjust the web page based on that. Otherwise, You can write a service and then consume it instead of parsing the HTML.